# Is there a scriptural basis for Out-of-India hypothesis?

Tags: history, culture, arya

I heard that Hindus believe that all Vedic-era people originated in Bhārat. Is this a cultural belief or is it from scripture?

---

The below non-Answers are "arguments against the mainstream theory" rather than Answers to the above question. Upvoting them is dishonest propagandizing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77530/discussion-on-question-by-rubellite-yak-is-there-a-scriptural-basis-for-out-of).

Comment: Please disregard reopen request

Comment: Looking back on this, it's very interesting that people related this question to Indo-Aryan migration. Out-of-Africa is the standard model for human migration. So, I was expecting the answers to pertain to that period (50-80,000 years ago, not ~4,000)

Comment: Not one of the answers can produce a scriptural support for their theory.

Answer (score 13):

## Why this is only unacceptable to Hindus.

No not only to the Hindus but it is well known in rest of the world that Aryan Invasion Theory is wrong.

It looks like you are more impressed with the 120 year myth created by F. Max Muller in 1848. And is biased towards western Indologist ,ignoring new research conducted by Hindu scholars and their opinions despite  the solid evidence provided by them and not mentioning thousands of articles present over the Internet showing that Aryan Migration Theory is Debunked.

Aryan Invasion Theory was  reinforced by western scholars on Hindu people (Hinduism) and on the rest of the world  and became the accepted history of Hinduism until some time back.

It is accused that the theory  is put forward for   racist ideas: These are some of the points I have compiled.

- it suggested that Indian culture was not a culture in its own right, but a synthesis of elements from other cultures
- it implied that Hinduism was not an authentically Indian religion but the result of cultural imperialism
- it suggested that Indian culture was static, and only changed under outside influences
- it suggested that the dark-skinned Dravidian people of the South of India had got their faith from light-skinned Aryan invaders
- it implied that indigenous people were incapable of creatively developing their faith
- it suggested that indigenous peoples could only acquire new religious and cultural ideas from other races, by invasion or other processes
- it accepted that race was a biologically based concept (rather than, at least in part, a social construct) that provided a sensible way of ranking people in a hierarchy, which provided a partial basis for the caste system
- it provided a basis for racism in the Imperial context by suggesting that the peoples of Northern India were descended from invaders from Europe and so racially closer to the British Raj.
- it gave a historical precedent to justify the role and status of the British Raj, who could argue that they were transforming India for the better in the same way that the Aryans had done thousands of years earlier
- it downgraded the intellectual status of India and its people by giving a falsely late date to elements of Indian science and culture.

  ---

  In books such as The Myth of the Aryan Invasion of India and In Search of the Cradle of Civilization, [**David Frawley**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Frawley) criticises the 19th century racial interpretations of Indian prehistory, such as the theory of a conflict between invading Caucasoid Aryans and Dravidians. In his Frawley along with [**Georg Feuerstein**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Feuerstein) and Subhash Kak has rejected the Aryan Invasion Theory and supported the Out of India theory.

> The Indus valley culture was pronounced pre-Aryans for several reasons
>   that were largely part of the cultural milieu of nineteenth century
>   European thinking. As scholars following Max Muller had decided that
>   the Aryans came into India around 1500 BC, since the Indus valley
>   culture was earlier than this, they concluded that it had to be
>   pre-Aryan. Yet the rationale behind the late date for the Vedic
>   culture given by Muller was totally speculative. **Max Muller, like many
>   of the Christian scholars of his era, believed in Biblical chronology.**
>   This placed the beginning of the world at 400 BC and the flood around
>   2500 BC. Assuming to those two dates, it became difficult to get the
>   Aryans in India before 1500 BC.

The Vedic culture was thus said to be that of primitive nomads who came out of Central Asia with their horse-drawn chariots and iron weapons and overthrew the cities of the more advanced Indus valley culture, with their superior battle tactics. It was pointed out that no horses, chariots or iron was discovered in Indus valley sites.

These are the points mentioned By David Frawley in his book.

1)  This was how the Aryan invasion theory formed and has remained since then. Though little has been discovered that confirms this theory, there has been much hesitancy to question it, much less to give it up.

2 ) Further excavations discovered horses not only in Indus Valley sites but also in pre-Indus sites. The use of the horse has thus been proven for the whole range of ancient Indian history. Evidence of the wheel, and an Indus seal showing a spoked wheel as used in chariots, has also been found, suggesting the usage of chariots.

3)  Moreover, the whole idea of nomads with chariots has been challenged. Chariots are not the vehicles of nomads. Their usage occured only in ancient urban cultures with much flat land, of which the river plain of north India was the most suitable. Chariots are totally unsuitable for crossing mountains and deserts, as the so-called Aryan invasion required.

Further excavation revealed that the Indus Valley culture was not destroyed by outside invasion, but according to internal causes and, most likely, floods. Most recently a new set of cities has been found in India (like the Dwaraka and Bet Dwaraka sites by S.R. Rao and the National Institute of Oceanography in India) which are intermediate between those of the Indus culture and later ancient India as visited by the Greeks. This may eliminate the so-called dark age following the presumed Aryan invasion and shows a continuous urban occupation in India back to the beginning of the Indus culture.

**In other words there is no racial evidence of any such Indo-Aryan invasion of India but only of a continuity of the same group of people who traditionally considered themselves to be Aryans.**

> According to this theory, the Vedic people were nomads in the Punjab,
>   coming down from Central Asia. However, the 'Rig Veda' itself has
>   nearly 100 references to ocean (samudra), as well as dozens of
>   references to ships, and to rivers flowing in to the sea. Vedic
>   ancestors like Manu, Turvasha, Yadu and Bhujyu are flood figures,
>   saved from across the sea. The Vedic God of the sea, Varuna, is the
>   father of many Vedic seers and seer families like Vasishta, Agastya
>   and the Bhrigu seers. **To preserve the Aryan invasion idea it was
>   assumed that the Vedic (and later Sanskrit) term for ocean, samudra,
>   originally did not mean the ocean but any large body of water,
>   especially the Indus river in Punjab. Here the clear meaning of a term
>   in 'Rig Veda' and later times - verified by rivers like Saraswati
>   mentioned by name as flowing into the sea - was altered to make the
>   Aryan invasion theory fit. Yet if we look at the index to translation
>   of the 'Rig Veda' by Griffith for example, who held to this idea that
>   samudra didn't really mean the ocean, we find over 70 references to
>   ocean or sea.** If samudra does not mean ocean, why was it translated as
>   such? It is therefore without basis to locate Vedic kings in Central
>   Asia far from any ocean or from the massive Saraswati river, which
>   form the background of their land and the symbolism of their hymns.

---

In a article Frawley  also talks about Aryan-Dravidian divide ,this is what he says.

> **Dravidian history does not contradict Vedic history** either. It credits
>   the invention of the Tamil language, the oldest Dravidian tongue, to
>   the **rishi Agastya**, one of the most prominent sages in the Rig Veda.
>   Dravidian kings historically have called themselves Aryans and trace
>   their descent through Manu (who in the Matsya Purana is regarded as
>   originally a south Indian king). Apart from language, moreover, both
>   north and south India share a common religion and culture. Prior to
>   Vedic Sanskrit there may have been a language that was the basis of
>   both the Dravidian and Sanskritic languages in India.

---

#### Research

Above all read this article - [**Harvard University’s international scandal unravels a global Hindu conspiracy.**](http://www.ivarta.com/columns/OL_051219.htm)

**North & South Bharatiyas Share Tissue Antigens, Distinct From Those of Europeans.**

**North & South Bharatiyas Share mtDNA, Which Is Distinct From That of Europeans**.

> Conclusion: The stark lack of similarities in the gene pools of the
>   Indian subcontinent and Europe, vividly evident in the mtDNA and the
>   MHC complex, destroys any ' Aryan invasion' notions, and confirms the
>   genetic uniformity of peoples of the Indian subcontinent. Chandrakant
>   Pansé, Professor of Biotechnology

---

Considering all this points  and based on many more such new conclusions  by Hindu scholars , Institutions  ,colleges both indian as well as western .Hindu people and Scholars strongly  deny Aryan Invasion Theory. And is dead. So it's not just Hindu People but rest of the world also.

Comment: "it suggested that Indian culture (is) a synthesis of elements from other cultures" Yes. As are almost all cultures. Source: I am an anthropologist

Comment: "it implie(s) that Hinduism (is) not an authentically Indian religion but the result of cultural imperialism" No. Hinduism is a result of endemic regional faiths & practices being incorporated into the Indo-Iranian system. This resulted in a Vedic religion that was uniquely "Indian."

Comment: "it suggested that Indian culture was static, and only changed under outside influences" No. I means that the new influence led to drastic changed. This is usually the case when people move in *en masse*.

Comment: "it suggested that the dark-skinned Dravidian people of the South of India had got their faith from light-skinned Aryan invaders" No. Again, they needn't be "invaders" and the DNA results suggest little animosity. Furthermore, both groups influenced each other which is clear when we see different emphases on different deities during different periods. The dark and light skin is irrelevant. The most relevant factor were the groups' (there were three, not just dark & light) subsistence techniques.

Comment: "it implied that indigenous people were incapable of creatively developing their faith" Just because something happens does not imply something else is impossible: If my SO brings me water, it doesn't imply I am incapable of getting my own water. What happened happened, other possibilities were still possible. Regardless, we would presume, just like every other culture, the indigenous peoples of Bharat did creatively develop their faith in addition to Indo-Iranians bringing in their faith as well.

Comment: "it suggested that indigenous peoples could only acquire new religious and cultural ideas from other races, by invasion or other processes" Again, no. New ideas came in. It is not the only way. Innovation is possible. Your argument is as spurious as a Japanese person claiming that they aren't the descendants of the native Jomon people **and** the ancient immigrant Yayoi people. Clearly the groups intermingled and modern Japanese people are the result. Why are you taking the claim of this common phenomenon so personally?

Comment: "it accepted that race was a biologically based concept (rather than, at least in part, a social construct) that provided a sensible way of ranking people in a hierarchy, which provided a partial basis for the caste system" No. There is no such thing as race. There is ethnicity. There are "common features among a group of people." But race doesn't exist. I think you are trying to argue against 19th century thinking instead of modern scientific understanding.

Comment: "it provided a basis for racism in the Imperial context by suggesting that the peoples of Northern India were descended from invaders from Europe and so racially closer to the British Raj." Certainly this happened, but this is not the fault of modern science. That is the fault of racist imperialists who accepted any justification for their actions they could get. The fact that Central Asians (not Europeans) migrated to the general area of the IVC via the BMAC is not actually related to the racist justification of the British.

Comment: "it gave a historical precedent to justify the role and status of the British Raj, who could argue that they were transforming India for the better in the same way that the Aryans had done thousands of years earlier" Again, yes the Aryan invasion hypothesis did do that. There was still a wave of migration that came in. We're fairly certain it wasn't an invasion, though. And again... you know... everything else I've already said

Comment: "it downgraded the intellectual status of India and its people by giving a falsely late date to elements of Indian science and culture." This is very interesting. What do you mean?

Comment: Reading through the rest of your "answer" I can see you are arguing against Max Muller (who I had never heard of until this debate), not against modern research. This is a straw man argument. Furthermore, I didn't ask for an argument over the facts (the facts are the facts)—my question is why don't Hindu's accept these facts. From your answer it seems to me it is because Muller made grave errors when a lot of science was still quite unreliable and racism was worse than it is now... because of this, some are still arguing against his terrible work and not even paying attention to new research

Comment: It is unsettling that this "answer" has so many upvotes. When it is arguing against very outdated science and completely ignores decades of research. And also, I have countered many of your points with no reply. Can we not rationally debate something at Hinduism.SE?? Thesis + antithesis => synthesis

Comment: I am  from a Hindu family. Let me try to explain - years of endogamy and patriarchy makes a bunch of aggressive idiots try to defend outdated unscientific drivel that seems to provide a shoddy justification for right-wing nationalism. There isn't really more to it than people who do it knowingly and those who never care to question the lies. The reality is that the scriptural, genetic, everything evidence for an Aryan migration out of the Eurasian steppes is definitely there. In the Battle of the Ten Kings, Viśvāmitra got the help of Central Asian tribes.

Comment: The family books mention the rivers rasā́, saráyū, sarásvatī - by their descriptions as turbulent rivers, and their clear Iranic cognates - Volga (Russia), Herat (Afghanistan), Arghandab (Afghanistan).

Comment: The most ideological of the right-wingers want to deny these connections to make out India to be the civilizational epicenter and deny our relations with our human kin in Pakistan, Iran, Vietnam, Nigeria, or the Amazon: according to Hindutva ideologues these people can only be kin to Indians if the Indians can spread their versions of Hinduism there and co-opt local traditions as their own, rather than seeing the shared humanity.

Comment: Also, this is literally only controversial in India or among people of Indian origin, and started to be so in the 1980s, according to something I recall reading a long time ago about the history of the fascistic RSS movement in India. Before the 1980s, the RSS ideologues considered themselves the proud descendants of Eastern European nomad invaders. Now, most serious scholars don't think hordes crossed the Khyber Pass in 1500BCE to wreak havoc on the indigenous peoples of Pakistan and India (at least, not most of the time).

Comment: The model Witzel puts forth is that nomads migrated across the Khyber Pass, eventually their descendants got real proud of their ancestry due to its convenience in justifying their rule, and justifying a nascent caste system. This is not an "Aryan Invasion Theory", but an "Aryan Migration Theory". Worth noting, that there are differences, although not that many, between the Aryan migrations of circa 1500BCE and the Turko-Afghan migrations of circa 1500CE. People have been coming to South Asia from Central Asia since forever, as human beings have been and do from everywhere to everywhere.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to @SwiftPushkar's excellent [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26665/13287):

**Argument A1)**

http://nature.com/articles/srep26555 from **"nature" journal** established that Harappan civilization is 8000 years old and collapsed due to weaker monsoon and climate change, not due to any invasion

---

---

**Argument A2)**

B. B. Lal is a renowned archeologist and former Director General of the Archaeological Survey of India (ASI) who has written many books and papers on the Aryan issue.

(1) Please read his reference book published **in 2015** "The Rigvedic People: Invaders?/ Immigrants? Or Indigenous?" by B B lal
https://www.amazon.in/Rigvedic-People-Invaders-Immigrants-Indigenous/dp/8173055351

(2) The summary of his book can be read in his interview here, where he debunks all the flaws in how marxists and western historians reached to their flawed conclusions
http://web.archive.org/web/20171124044705/https://www.newsgram.com/no-evidence-for-warfare-or-invasion-aryan-migration-too-is-a-myth-b-b-lal

This book debunks aryan migration theory(AMT)

---

---

**Argument A3)**

See this **genetic study** by a [CCMB instiute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre_for_Cellular_and_Molecular_Biology) which debunks AMT/AIT theory 
 https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Aryan-Dravidian-divide-a-myth-Study/articleshow/5053274.cms

---

---

**Argument A4)**

pro-AMT

(disclaimer:Now, my next discussions are not links from journals and peer reviewed books, but from newspaper and sites, but this is for addon discussion.)
 the article by Tony joseph on "How genetics is settling the Aryan migration debate" **in year 2017** supports aryan migration theory
http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/how-genetics-is-settling-the-aryan-migration-debate/article19090301.ece

---

anti-AMT

(disclaimer:Now, my next discussions are not links from journals and peer reviewed books, but from newspaper and sites, but this is for addon discussion.)
But that Hindu article by Tony joseph and similar articles have been comprehensively critiqued by researchers in 2018 study

https://www.thenewsminute.com/article/dna-and-aryan-debate-why-articles-hindu-indus-are-missing-larger-point-74201

https://swarajyamag.com/ideas/genetics-might-be-settling-the-aryan-migration-debate-but-not-how-left-liberals-believe

http://indiafacts.org/propagandizing-aryan-invasion-debate-rebuttal-tony-joseph/

---

---

**argument A5)**

also see [Aryan Migration theory—evidence for and against it in the Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/aryan-invasion-theory-evidence-for-and-against-it-in-the-vedas)

---

---

**argument A6)**

Racial intepretation of **"Dravida"** term as "non-aryan" by western historians, is debunked in this paper https://www.academia.edu/1573411/Vedic_Roots_of_Early_Tamil_Culture  and summarised in this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2321/13287

---

---

**argument A7)**

Dr. B R Ambedkar also debunked Arya Invasion/Migration Theory https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.282497 see chapter 4 (additional urls http://www.opindia.com/2018/04/dr-ambedkar-rejected-aryan-invasion-theory-with-facts-and-logic and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Were_the_Shudras%3F ) . Dr. Ambedkar provides an alternative explanation of **"shudras** origination" , instead of racial (non-aryan) interpretation by western historians about shudras origination

---

---

**Argument A8)**

In the book "Indo-Aryan Controversy Evidence And Inference In Indian History Routledge ( 2005)" authored by "Edwin Bryant, Laurie Patton (Eds.)", published in  2005 ; the authors have in detail re-evaluated all the arguments pro and against the AMT till date in modern times, and then arrived the conclusion that AMT is false

ref:
https://archive.org/details/EdwinBryantLauriePattonIndoAryanControversyEvidenceAndInferenceInIndianHistoryRoutledge2005

https://ia801904.us.archive.org/0/items/EdwinBryantLauriePattonIndoAryanControversyEvidenceAndInferenceInIndianHistoryRoutledge2005/Edwin%20Bryant%2C%20Laurie%20Patton-Indo-Aryan%20Controversy_%20Evidence%20and%20Inference%20in%20Indian%20History-Routledge%20%282005%29.pdf

---

---

**Argument A9)**

for detailed arguments by Stephen knapp, read here

https://www.stephen-knapp.com/death_of_the_aryan_invasion_theory.htm

book: "The Aryan Invasion Theory: The Final Nail in its Coffin"
https://www.amazon.in/Aryan-Invasion-Theory-Final-Coffin-ebook/dp/B00AEIHF2Y/ref=pd_typ_k_sp_1_2/259-1374969-7588913?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=06Z8C3G0W65JZHPFN560

---

**Argument 11)** also related- see answers given in:

- [Aryan Migration theory—evidence for and against it in the Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/aryan-migration-theory-evidence-for-and-against-it-in-the-vedas/21494#21494)
- [Aryan Migration theory—evidence for and against it in the Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/aryan-invasion-theory-evidence-for-and-against-it-in-the-vedas?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Is there any Hindu spiritual principle that causes many Hindus to oppose the Aryan Migration Theory?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27273/is-there-any-hindu-spiritual-principle-that-causes-many-hindus-to-oppose-the-ary)
- Early Humans Settled India Before Europe, Study Suggests
  https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2005/11/1114_051114_india.html
  https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2005/11/1114_051114_india_2.html
- [Were Aryans the forefathers of Hindus?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11/were-aryans-the-forefathers-of-hindus/41#41)
- [Vedic Age and Hindu Timeline](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24057/vedic-age-and-hindu-timeline/24062#24062)
- https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/kolkata/a-900-yr-drought-ended-indus-civilisation-says-iit-kgp-study/articleshow/63776598.cms?from=mdr
- [Were Aryans the forefathers of Hindus?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11/were-aryans-the-forefathers-of-hindus/43#43)
- http://talageri.blogspot.com/2018/04/what-is-value-of-new-genomic-evidence.html?m=1
- https://swarajyamag.com/ideas/why-the-latest-genetic-study-does-not-rewrite-indias-history

Comment: You can add these links in the answer if it addresses the questions. Comments are not for links.  Add directly in the answer.

Comment: Again you are not answering the question. Firstly, the claim isn't that BMAC migrated to (& certainly not invaded) the Indus Valley. It was people living north of them. They passed through the BMAC lands on their way there. I'm sure BB Lal is very smart, but he is making a straw man argument—or at the very least he is having an argument no one is opposing him on. I'll get to the arguments 3~7 another time. Regardless, your answer is not answering the question at hand.

Comment: **[Point1]**
before revisions of this question by yourself, your question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/26658 was 
"Why do some Hindus believe Steppe pastoralists didn't migrateno one ever migrated into South Asia?
 Steppe pastoralists immigrated to India displacing the agriculturalists who were at the time living in the Punjab region. These farmers then migrated south and east displacing hunter-gatherers who were living there."

Comment: **[Point2]**
the another answer by you only https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26154/when-did-untouchability-start/26155#26155 , which was "linked here" in this question before revision - still captures you saying that -->
"The Dalits were Dravidians living in the hinterlands. The incoming Indo-Aryans drove many south & east. Since they had no role in "civilized society" they had no caste. As the Vedic culture spread, they were looked down upon for their lack of advancement and low utility to society. Some found employ where they could doing the jobs no one else would.

Comment: **continued of [Point2]** .."This took place before around the 12th century BCE"     (end of quoted statement of yours)

Comment: **[conclusion]** --> So it means you were earlier talking about Aryan migration . But, now you have changed/edited your question to "Why do some Hindus believe 'no one ever' migrated into South Asia?". And then after changing your question fundamentally, you are claiming to me that "I am not answering your question". Sorry to say, but this is intellectual dishonesty on your part.

Comment: related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/aryan-invasion-theory-evidence-for-and-against-it-in-the-vedas?noredirect=1&lq=1
 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27273/is-there-any-hindu-spiritual-principle-that-causes-many-hindus-to-oppose-the-ary and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11/were-aryans-the-forefathers-of-hindus/43#43
 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2321/13287

Comment: I say those things because they are true. But, I have found that the word "Aryan" is toxic here. You know, in science,when we realize we are wrong, we admit it and fix the theory. We don't throw out the idea entirely. When I say Aryan, it doesn't mean a race, it means an ethnicity coming from Central Asia. Those people fought and replaced some of the rulers in the Indus Valley. These events are clear. But, when I speak truth I get the kind of terrible answers I have gotten on this question and then it gets closed. So, I edited the question to make it clear I don't want to debate the science

Comment: I want to know WHY otherwise intelligent people deny history. Is it because of scripture? culture? hurt feelings? not caring about updates to the concept? In the US, we call it "throwing the baby out with the bath water." I have not edited anything to deceive. I edited to clarify the question and stop people thinking I am talking about Muller. No one agrees with Muller, so why is it in the answer??

Comment: Please do not confuse miscommunication for dishonesty. Question fixed.

Comment: @Rubellite the problen with the historians & anthropologist  is that you guys Conclude something unidirectionally based on various  **available** premises. But the work of fate is not limited to your intellect. Itisnotnecessary that  things should or might have workEd based on your ownlimited understanding derived from limited available sources.  Will of lord works in various ways which your historians  & various -logists can't know. Sorry, historians & anthropologists are not authority  to us. Scriptures are.  Scriptures are valid source of knowledge  in hindu schools

Comment: And Since no any historian or various -logist is omniscient  enough to see past events nor were they provided with complete information (rather were provided with limited available past information in bits & pieces)  they are not worthy accepted as valid means of knowledge  to us. What happened  some thousands  years back can not be discerned  by anyone scientifically.  One can only speculate  what happened  looking at bits & pieces.

Comment: @Rohit. By your logic we are faulty for trying to understand something with limited information. You realize that is every science, right? When we get new info, we happily adopt a new understanding. You can't scare scientists by telling them their information is limited. That is given. The alternative would be to give up and not try to understand anything. I never demanded to be an authority. It's up to you if you want to believe a theory or not. You choose to disbelieve before trying to understanding it. And, how is this related to the question? What is the scriptural basis for your belief?

Comment: "Scriptures are valid source of knowledge in hindu schools"

Which is why I asked for the scriptural basis for Out-of-India hypothesis

Comment: @Rubellite Wrong analogy. And I'm not gonna invalidate everything. If pratyaksha is in conflict with scriptural knowledge  then pratyaksha is taken valid due to its priority. Direct scientific  experiments what physicists, chemists etc perform comes under pratyaksha. But anthropology,  history  don't come under pratyaksha so scriptures are validated over these ries or logies. And my Comments were not related to your question but toyour replies spreaded hither and tither.

Comment: @Rubellite Yaksi you said "When I say Aryan, it doesn't mean a race, it means an ethnicity coming from Central Asia. Those people fought and replaced some of the rulers in the Indus Valley. These events are clear. But, when I speak truth I get the kind of terrible answers I have gotten on this question and then it gets closed" . My reply: (1)You have not offerred a single/single convincing proof in support of your theory, and you think that others should blindly accept that whatever you are proclaiming is true, without questioning you.

Comment: Without giving any supporting evidence, you continue to say that  'These events are clear'.  How come your proposed events are automatically and automagically clear and clear to whom and what is the proof of them being clear (2) without refuting the arguments here in any way, you just dismiss that these are terrible answers. You are yourself being rude , unscientific, blindly dismissive of the effort people put in giving comprehensive answers to you. And it is you who are still in complain mode. You need to come out of blame mode and  re-think rationally .

Comment: First give some real tangible proof of your own hypothesis without automagically assuming them ; and then recompare the tangibility with proofs given here.

Comment: and your post was already closed since long. But you edited your question again yesterday, and this time  you pointed not to a particular duplicate question, but to a particular answer, which suits you. "And then you added "Request Close as duplicate." on 11 May 2018; even though the question was already closed on 12 April 2018 by admins. Why are you mega-negatively manipulating so much, and then you are blaming around others.

Comment: @Rohit. Well, anthropology is a science, but that aside, what is the actual scripture that overrides it? That's all I've been asking for this whole time.

Comment: @zaxebo1 "You have not offerred a single/single convincing proof in support of your theory, and you think that others should blindly accept that whatever you are proclaiming is true, without questioning you." Because I am not trying to change any minds. I'm trying to learn, but people want to argue with Max Muller instead of answer my query. 
 "clear to whom and what is the proof of them being clear" Well, frankly I don't have the time nor desire to summarize a dozen papers on linguistics, genetics, forensics, & archaeology. In the same way I wouldn't ask you to tell me the Ramayana.

Comment: The information is out there for those desiring to know. Why should I waste effort trying to pry open closed minds? I don't mind that you all believe contrary to the evidence. I want to know what the basis for believing thus is. "Why are you mega-negatively manipulating so much, and then you are blaming around others." I change the question because it is clear that no one has understood what I am asking. Look at the answers, none of them tell me what I've been wanting to know. None of them even argued against modern theories. The edit history is freely available for anyone to see.

Comment: If—instead of trying to malign and argue with me—you would answer my query, then you'll have educated me and this will be over with. You can also help by pointing out specifically where I blamed someone else. I do not want to behave thus. Please show me where I've erred that I may fix my flaws.

Comment: I "Request Close as duplicate" because my question was already asked, but I was the only one who noticed it. Unfortunately that question wasn't answered from scripture either, so I linked the person who said it is not in scripture. To close it as "scientific speculation" is to misunderstood what I was asking all along

Comment: Now the question is again changed 11th time ,  now entire direction of inititlal question has been changed, as always. This questioner is continuously obsessively manipulating, just to show that given answers are something different.

Answer (score -1):

Aryan Invasion is a straw man.  Westerners and mainstream Indian researchers and academics have moved on Aryan Migration.  The "God of the sea" - Narayana occurs only in later scriptures - hard to explain if Rig Veda was produced by people to to whom the sea was important.  Himalaya hardly finds mention in Rig Veda - once again showing the Western origin of the Aryas.

What the Puranas did to Magnificent gods like Mitra and Varuna (something absent from other Indo-European mythologies) shows that there was a cultural shift of Rig Vedic people after contact with Indians.  Without any recourse to DNA - it is beyond a shadow of a doubt that there was a cultural migration from the Northwest to Afghanistan/Pakistan/NorthWest India to produce the foundational scripture - Rig Veda.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75858/discussion-on-answer-by-s-k-why-do-hindus-believe-steppe-pastoralists-didnt-mig).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The chat seems to have disappeared. If possible, please move relevant information to: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84439/discussion-of-vedic-homeland

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī seems that the link you provided is now dead too. Not sure where it is people are discussing this topic, if at all.

Comment: @abhishek I guess the SE is too inactive for such discussions to occur in chats (the chats disappear after enough time of inactivity) even though we're not to have them in comments? ‍♀️